# Javascript object is not function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and am confused about the error messages I get:

I have the JavaScript Code:

```
function tile(x,y) {
return ((worldw * y) + x);
}

alert(tile(5,5));
```

But I get the error message in Chrome that "Object is not a function".

How can I fix this and what does the error message mean?

Comment: worldw is a static variable defined as varworldw = 50;

Comment: `varworldw = 50;` is hopefully a typo. That should be `var worldw = 50;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine in Chrome and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), if I replace `worldw` with a numeric value. So I do not see an issue based on what you posted.

What is `worldw`, and can you post more code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I realised the problem was just I had stupidly got an array called tile as well and so it was calling that, not the function :/ Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense... in any case, sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. Glad you got it working!